# Consider the solution set S of the linear equation $x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 = 1$ in $\Bbb R^3$ . Calculate the distance of the point (1, 1, 1) from S.

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Consider the solution set $S$ of the linear equation $x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 = 1$ in $\Bbb R^3$. Calculate the distance of the point $(1, 1, 1)$ from $S$.
I thought at first that you can make a matrix of the linear equation of set $S$ and then calculate the outcomes of $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$. When this is done you can calculate the distance between the two points with the square root of the sum of the squares of the differences between corresponding coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! There exists a general formula for that.

Comment: I cannot find this formula anywhere. Do you know this formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just how to calculate the distance from a point to an hyperplane: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_plane

In your case: let $\underline{x}=(x,y,z)=(1, 1, 1)$ and $S: ax_1+bx_2+cx_3=d$. Now $$d(x,S)=\frac{|ax+by+cz-d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=\frac{|1*1+2*1+1*1-1|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2+1^2}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{6}}=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}$$

Comment: But how is it possible that you have 3 free variables in the set S and only one final answer? I mean in order to get 1 you can have multiple sets of S right?

Comment: The set $S$ represents a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The distance from a point to a plane is defined as the distance from the closest point in the plane to our point

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to obtain the general formula for the distance of a point $M_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to the plane $\Pi$ with equation $\;ax+by+cz=d$:

Remember the vector $\vec n=(a,b,c)$ is normal to the plane $\Pi$. If $H$ is the orthogonal projection of $M_0$ onto $\Pi$, we'll use the parametric  equation of the perpendicular line  to $\Pi$, $(M_0H)$: it is (in vector notation):
$$M=M_0+t\,\vec n.$$

The value of $t$ for $H$ is characterised  by the fact that $H$ satisfies the vector equation of $\Pi$:
$$\vec n\cdot \overrightarrow{OH}=\vec n\cdot \overrightarrow{OM}_0+ t \,\vec n\cdot\vec n=ax_0+by_0+cz_0+t\|\vec n\|^2=d,$$
so that $\;t=\dfrac{d-ax_0-by_0-cz_0}{\|\vec n\|^2}.$

Now the sought distance is $\;\|\overrightarrow{M_0H}\|=\|t\,\vec n\|=|t|\|n\|$, and eventually
$$d(M_0,\Pi)=\frac{|d-ax_0-by_0-cz_0|}{\|\vec n\|^2}\,\|\vec n\|=\frac{|ax_0+by_0+cz_0-d|}{\|\vec n\|}. $$